# Reindex rows of a a dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Having a data frame as below:

```
data = {'number':[4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,5],'name':['L6','L6','L6','L6','L6','L8','L8','L8','L9','L9','L8','L9'],
    'product1':['B','C','A','A','A','A','B','B','D','D','D','E'],
    'product2':['D','A','B','Z','C','G','G','T','E','W','T','Q']}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Needs to replace all the rows or reindex the rows at the begining of the dataframe based on a list.

```
lst = [(3,'L6','A'),(3,'L8','B'),(3,'L9','D')]
```

The below figure shows the expected output:

[image: img]

Answer (score 3):

Use [`pd.MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html) and [`get_indexer_for`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer_for.html) to get the indexes for the values in my_list.

Then find remaining indexes by using [`np.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) with `np.arange(len(df))` and first indexes found

Then use [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) to combine those to get the desired order of indexes

Then [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) df with new order.

```
my_list = [(3,'L6','A'),(3,'L8','B'),(3,'L9',D)] #Don't use 'list' for name
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df['number'], df['name'], df['product1']])
first_rows_indexes = mi.get_indexer_for(my_list)
remaining_indexes = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(len(df)), first_rows_indexes)
df = df.reindex(np.concatenate([first_rows_indexes, remaining_indexes]))
```

print(df):

```
    number name product1 product2
2        3   L6        A        B
3        3   L6        A        Z
4        3   L6        A        C
6        3   L8        B        G
7        3   L8        B        T
8        3   L9        D        E
9        3   L9        D        W
0        4   L6        B        D
1        3   L6        C        A
5        3   L8        A        G
10       4   L8        D        T
11       5   L9        E        Q
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a dataframe from the list of tuples, then outer merge with given dataframe to automatically sort based on the order of keys in lst

```
order = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['number', 'name', 'product1'])
order.merge(df, how='outer', sort=False)
```

---

```
    number name product1 product2
0        3   L6        A        B
1        3   L6        A        Z
2        3   L6        A        C
3        3   L8        B        G
4        3   L8        B        T
5        3   L9        D        E
6        3   L9        D        W
7        4   L6        B        D
8        3   L6        C        A
9        3   L8        A        G
10       4   L8        D        T
11       5   L9        E        Q
```